# Is there way to fix accept language or currency?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, currency, http-accept-language

I would like to ask how to fix random currency bacause iam trying to make price checker but when i run it for the firt time it gave me the currency in swedish crowns and the few minutes later it gave me different currency i tried accept language and it worked like only 10 minutes and then it changed again and again is there any way to fix it? There is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/USP-S%20%7C%20Blueprint%20%28Factory%20New%29"
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html_text = requests .get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/USP-S%20%7C%20Blueprint%20%28Factory%20New%29').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
skin_name = soup.find('span', class_ = 'market_listing_item_name').text
sm = soup.find('span', class_ = 'market_listing_price').text.replace('                      ','SM ')
print(skin_name, sm)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the website, you'll see that the price actually depends on the seller and not you, so it doesn't matter what `headers` (including `Accept-language`) you use.

Secondly you're using `soup.find` which just returns the first occurrence, so it's mostly based on luck what you'll find.

I recommend you to use `soup.find_all` and looping over it to find the first price in dollars.

```
sm_list = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'market_listing_price')
for element in sm_list:
    if 'USD' in element.text:
        sm = element.text.replace('                      ','SM ')
print(skin_name, sm)
```